# Are there libraries for extraction of sound wave features?

Tags: audio, frequency, sound, pitch

I am looking help for my project for which I need C++ (or any other language) libraries useful for extraction of sound wave features like **frequency, loudness, pitch and orientation**. Using these features I want to make **attention** in a humanoid robot simulator .

Answer (score 7):

From the ones I've been using I can recommend:

- [YAAFE](http://yaafe.sourceforge.net/) - very pleasant to work with in Python
- [ESSENTIA](http://essentia.upf.edu/) - another one I like particularly due to Python integration
- [aubio](http://aubio.org/)
- [FEAPI](http://feapi.sourceforge.net/)
- [Aquila](http://aquila-dsp.org/features/) - friend of mine used it extensively and he likes it a lot

---

Recently I came across this paper and I believe that this should perfectly answer your question.

> [*Moffat D. et al* - **An Evaluation of Audio Feature Extraction
>   Toolboxes**](https://www.ntnu.edu/documents/1001201110/1266017954/DAFx-15_submission_43_v2.pdf/06508f48-9272-41c8-9381-7639a0240770)

They do provide a detailed comparison based on:

- Amount of features available
- Ease of usage
- Output format of the features
- Computational efficiency

They tested following libraries:

- Aubio
- Essentia
- jAudio
- Librosa
- LibXtract
- Marsyas
- Meyda
- MIR Toolbox
- Timbre Toolbox
- YAAFE

Answer (score 2):

I can highly recommend [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/) (python), for its intuitive API and excellent [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) integration, which is useful for quickly using extracted features in a machine learning pipeline).

Check out some examples: [introduction](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/bmcfee/librosa/blob/master/examples/LibROSA%20demo.ipynb), scikit-learn [integration demo](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/bmcfee/librosa/blob/master/examples/LibROSA%20sklearn%20feature%20pipeline.ipynb).

Comment: First link (to librosa) is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB:

- [MIR toolbox](https://www.jyu.fi/hum/laitokset/musiikki/en/research/coe/materials/mirtoolbox)
- [Auditory toolbox](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~malcolm/interval/1998-010/)

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain yourself?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think it's because this is a link-only answer, which we prefer to avoid on all *.SE sites. Care to give a sentence on WHY those toolboxes might help the OP?